# How to list the files and folders inside a partition

Tags: partitioning

I made a backup of my home directory to a new partition that i created /sdb1. Now I want to check if the files and folders of my home directory are actually copied in the partition. I noticed that I can not cd in the partition and ls its contents. How can I do something like that?

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo dump -0 -f /dev/sdb1 ~
ls /dev/sdb1
```

Another thing that happens here is that sdb1 after executing dump appears to be unformated.

Comment: You must if course `mount` it first.

Comment: I have already mounted it

Comment: Please edit your post to show (1) the command used to copy the contents of your home directory and (2) the commands you tried for changing directory and listing the files.

Comment: run `lsblk -f` paste the results.

Comment: Also, if you `cd` into `/dev/sdb1`, you can just use `ls -a`.

Comment: @AlanDiggs You can't cd into /dev/sdb1. It's a device, not a directory. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After you mounted `/dev/sdb1` on `/mnt`,  you must check the existence of the file inside `/mnt`

```
ls /mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

- Most programs operate at the filesystem level, where data structures are 
  files and metadata
- `dump`, like `dd`, operates at the device 
  level, where there are no data structures, just binary.
- `/dev/sdb1` is a device, not a directory, so you need to mount it to make 
  it accessible for programs that operate at the filesystem level.

So, to do what you want, you need to operate on the mountpoint, not the device:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt # Mount the device to the mountpoint.
cd /mnt                   # Now you can cd, use ls, or read the files
```